# successive errors on hadoop :failed on connection exception then com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

i am trying to execute the command `hadoop dfs -ls`, and i got this error

```
Call From localhost/127.0.0.1 to yass-SATELLITE-C855-2CF:8021 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

once i resolved i got another which is

```
ls: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.; Host Details : local host is: "localhost/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "yass-SATELLITE-C855-2CF":9000;
```

and i keep in loop between this two errors

my `core-site.xml`

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://yass-SATELLITE-C855-2CF:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

`hdfs-site.xml`

```
<property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
     </property>
<property>
        <name>dfs.safemode.threshold.pct</name>
        <value>0</value>
    </property>
  <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>/hadoop/data/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>/hadoop/data/datanode</value>
    </property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>/home/yass/Téléchargements/hadoop/hdfs/name</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.use.datanode.hostname</name>
    <value>false</value>
 </property>

  <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check</name>
     <value>false</value>
  </property>
```

`etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1   localhost   
127.0.0.1   yass-SATELLITE-C855-2CF

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

i got the first exception once it dispair i got the second one and i keep always in loop with this two exceptions
Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 0):

in reality i find somehow a solution in order to not staying with same errors
so i installed `Hadoop verion 2.6.2` ,configure the version using the XML then keep working ,is not good solution for everyone but i hope that will show light for others